Main function returns before all routines finish their job
I am trying to implement a file finder using goroutines to faster traverse the file system. I have two functions. One of them (walkDirSendMatchingNames) walks through directories and sends paths that match a regexp to the path_channel. The second one (dummyFilter) just resend data tho the mod_channel. This is imitation of some additional filtering, like modification date, etc. And finally, in the main function I read from mod_channel and print to the stdout.
Current implementation does not work as supposed because sometimes it prints matching files and sometimes not. It looks like main function return before dummyFilter sends data to the channel. Could someone help me to come up with a better architecture?
type File struct {
     d    os.DirEntry
     path string
}
func walkDirSendMatchingNames(root string, re *regexp.Regexp, path_channel chan<- File, ignore_dot bool, wg *sync.WaitGroup) error {
    defer wg.Done()
    visit := func(path string, d os.DirEntry, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("Could not read directory %s: %s\n", path, err)
        }
        if ignore_dot && strings.HasPrefix(d.Name(), ".") {
            return nil
        }
        if d.IsDir() && path != root {
            wg.Add(1)
            go walkDirSendMatchingNames(filepath.Join(root, d.Name()), re, path_channel, ignore_dot, wg)
            return filepath.SkipDir
        } else {
            if re.Match([]byte(d.Name())) {
                path_channel <- File{d, filepath.Join(root, d.Name())}
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    return filepath.WalkDir(root, visit)
}
func dummyFilter(path_channel <-chan File, mod_channel chan<- string) {
    for file_struct := range path_channel {
        mod_channel <- file_struct.path
    }
}
func main() {
    path := "."
    re, err := regexp.Compile("file")

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    path_channel := make(chan File)
    mod_channel := make(chan string)

    wg.Add(1)
    go walkDirSendMatchingNames(path, re, path_channel, true, &wg)

    go dummyFilter(path_channel, mod_channel)

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(path_channel)
        close(mod_channel)
    }()

    for path := range mod_channel {
        fmt.Println(path)
    }

}



Move the close(mod_channel) to the end of dummyFilter. That way it will be closed after the last value in path_channel has been processed, currently you might drop one result (example). "not work as supposed" - please provide details (ideally the output), I can see that you might drop the last result but it looks like prior results should be output.

As you've said, I've been missing the last result. But not always. One out of ten (approximately) was successful. Moving close(mod_channel) to the end of dummyFilter solved the problem. Thanks! Now I guess, I should always close a channel at the end of  the function that sends data to that channel.

Given that the behavior is similar to "Initialize -> Execute -> Finalize/Clean up", why not add an instance to the WorkGroup for dummyFilter? You'd need to do there as you're going in walkDirSendMatchingNames of course (i.e., wg.Done()), but then you'd make sure that the channel wouldn't close before its task is complete.
I'm referring to these lines
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(path_channel)
        close(mod_channel)
    }()

If walkDirSendMatchingNames finishes too quickly, the WorkGroup will be considered done and the channels will be closed. By adding dummyFilter to the group, you can guarantee that the above goroutine will only close the channels when both are done

I guess if I add dummyFilter to the group, I will  sleep until it finishes to close channels. But it will not finish because I wait for him to finish to close the channel)

Didn't get that point. Could you elaborate, @mli?

Thanks for staying, @Caique. dummyFilter returns when the path_channel is closed. In the code we close that channel in the lines you've highlighted. But there is wg.Wait(). So we will wait for all the goroutines to finish (including dummyFilter). But dummyFilter will finish only when we close the channel. So deadlock.

As suggested by @Brits, moving close(mod_channel) to the end of the dummyFilter solved the problem. Many thanks!

Kindly mark the comment as the correct answer.
